# Simple Java applet not working on Internet Explorer

Tags: java, applet

I've got a Hello World applet:

```
import java.applet.Applet; 
import java.awt.Graphics; 

// HelloWorld class extends Applet 
public class HelloWorld extends Applet  
{ 
    // Overriding paint() method 
    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g)  
    { 
        g.drawString("Hello World", 20, 20); 
    } 

}
```

with HTML:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello World Applet</title>
</head>

<body>
<applet code="HelloWorld.class" width=200 height=600>
</applet>    
</body>
</html>
```

I know that Firefox doesn't support Java Applets anymore so I tried Internet Explorer. I've put all the security options but the "Hello World" won't show! On the other hand appletviewer.exe works. Thanks for reply and best regards,
Adi.

Comment: Just curious. In this day and age why an applet?

Comment: It is 2019 and Applets are no longer supported in any browser. appletviewer is all that's left, and even that has been removed in recent versions of Java.

Comment: I need it for experimental purposes :-)

Comment: Sweet memories took me back to 2006. You may have to try older version of IE 6?

Comment: Pasupathi, do you mean "older version than IE 6" or "older version than IE 11 (which I use currently)"?

Comment: Would I have to uninstall IE11 to install IE6?

Comment: Why don't you use a VM — if you really really really want applets?

Comment: @Ady I remember using applets around 2006 to 2010 using this timeline graph, guessing it would work on old IE version. You can give it a try. 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_web_browsers
Alternatively https://java.com/en/download/faq/firefox_java.xml FF 52ESR supports

Comment: *"I need it for experimental purposes"* What's the experiment? If it's 'do browsers still support applets?' we can settle that right now. No, they don't. For any other sort of experiment, do it in a Swing based `JFrame`.

Comment: We know it's you, Marty Mac Fly. Does the DeLorean only work with an applet or what?

Comment: @JBNizet "Java Software is not designed or intended for use in the design, construction, operation or maintenance of any nuclear facility or nuclear powered time machine." ;)

Comment: @JBNizet Maybe after the incident with Biff, the flux capacitor uses a [Java ring](https://people.cs.uchicago.edu/~dinoj/smartcard/javaring.html) for authentication and authorization?